# parameterized algorithms for geometric set cover

Tags: reference-request, cg.comp-geom, parameterized-complexity

Are there any parametrized algorithms $W$-hardness results known for the computational problem Geometric Set Cover?

It is known that set cover problem is $W[2]$ hard when parametrized by the solution size? There might be some advantages when the sets are defined by geometric objects.

Comment: What is W[2] hardness?

Comment: @Bagaria See [W hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity#W_hierarchy), and may be before that reading [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/dealing-with-intractability-np-complete-problems/11773#11773) roughly explanation is easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper D. Marx: Efficient approximation schemes for geometric problems?, in ESA 2005, gives W[1](http://www.cs.bme.hu/~dmarx/papers/marx-esa2005.pdf)-hardness for covering points with unit squares. A draft is [here](http://www.cs.bme.hu/~dmarx/papers/marx-esa2005.pdf).

Comment: There is hardness of k-center clustering if the dimension is high enough.

http://www.cs.bme.hu/~dmarx/papers/cabello-covering-talg.pdf

There are PTASes for some variants of geometric set-cover, so it seems unlikely that it is W[2]-hard for all variants.